# InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, protocol-buffers

I have installed Hadoop 2.6.0 on my Ubuntu-VM.
I followed the steps on this site :
http://qursaan-howto.blogspot.fr/2014/12/how-to-install-hadoop-as-single-node-on.html

All has been working fine for me, but I still have this error:

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir /usr/hive/warehouse
mkdir: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "ubuntu/127.0.1.1"; destination host is: "localhost":9000;
```

start-all.sh : works fine
jps

```
2836 SecondaryNameNode
3420 Jps
2965 ResourceManager
2688 DataNode
3079 NodeManager
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to suggest you have a networking error...

In the official Hadoop documentation install guide, it explicitly says to edit `/etc/hosts` to remove `127.0.1.1` entries from the file, which is used in the error output you have.